# Open Tkinter multiple Windows with delay (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, image, tkinter

I've been trying to open several Tkinter windows with a delay of couple seconds between each Tkinter window.

My Script so far :

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from time import sleep
from random import uniform

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("10x10")
l = []

def showPic(i):
    if(i<5):
        loc = os.getcwd() + '\pictures\pic%s.jpg' % i
        img = Image.open(loc)
        img.load()
        photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        l.append(photoImg)
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry("750x750+%d+%d" % (uniform(0, GetSystemMetrics(0) - 750),     uniform(0, GetSystemMetrics(1) - 750)))
        tk.Label(window, text="this is window %s" % i).pack()
        tk.Label(window, image=photoImg).pack()
        root.after(1000, showPic(i+1))
    else:
        return


root.after(0, showPic(1))
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried using the sleep() and after() functions with no success.
It waits the time before preparing the window, but shows them all together, simultaniously, after the time I set

Comment: `after` expects function name without () and arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after` expects function name without `()` and arguments

Using

```
root.after(1000, showPic(i+1))
```

is like

```
result = showPic(i+1)
root.after(1000, result)
```

You can use `lambda`

```
root.after(1000, lambda:showPic(i+1))
```

because it is almost like

```
def new_function():
    showPic(i+1)

root.after(1000, new_function)
```

or

```
root.after(1000, showPic, i+1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! was stuck for so long. Much appreciated!